# Change graphic in Excel

Tags: vb.net, image, excel, shapes

I have an Excelfile with a picture in it.

Now I want to change the picture with VB. How do I do this?
I tried it with

```
Dim anwendung As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook = anwendung.Workbooks.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\Ausgaben\Ausgabe.xls")


Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet = wbk.Worksheets("Kennzahlen")
wks.Shapes(1).Picture = LoadPicture(Application.StartupPath + "\Ausgaben\Leistungsdiagramm.tif")
```

But he doesnt know the LoadPicture-Method...
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of picture object use a Shape object (Rectangular), and use this code:

```
 Sheets(1).Shapes(1).Fill.UserPicture ("e:\0\a\untitled.png")
```

beacause LoadPictuer load only BMP files.

Comment: Thx. I found my mistake.

Shapes(1) doesnt work in VB. You have to go with Shapes.item(1).